# Unserialize array from database with javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, node.js

hey i have a serialize array from database like this

```
a:3:{i:0;s:2:"12";i:1;s:2:"13";i:2;s:2:"14";}
```

all i want to parse that array with javascript. i have doing `JSON.parse()` but still not working , can you help me? if in PHP there's `unserialize($var)` is there possible `unsrialize(var)` in javascript ? by the way i use nodejs express.

Comment: Its not a valid JSON. Hence JSON.parse is failing

Comment: This is not a valid json, are you sure you receive this data ?

Comment: How do you end up with that data? It doesn't resemble anything I've ever seen.

Comment: i'm doing that serialize in PHP, but i have application which is nodejs, so i need to parse that serialize array.

Comment: Please post the code that retrieve the data from the database. Where do you see this data ? Did you use `console.log()` ?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can use this lib:

https://github.com/naholyr/js-php-unserialize

But in general, I can't understand why do you need this. Just convert in to the JSON object in PHP, then work without troubles with it in JS.

Comment: I can't understand poeple who can't understand that web is complex and not all developpers are aware of good practices.
You may need to treat data from another app, which return a serialized php array in a JS APP.

Basicaly the developper should have return a json object, it's not the case we have to deal with it.
So the end of your response is useless, as it's for so many stack responses.

Comment: @DrK, not sure what you want to point out with your comment. 
The answer was helpful to the user (it has a solution to the problem),
and it contains suggestion, that it's not wise to use PHP internal format for the external communication;
if you have a better suggestion, please write your own answer, if you have some suggestions on how to make the answer more clear, please clarify

Comment: It was not completely helpfull the end of your statement was not helping at all.
I had the case where I had to use this library, if your stuck with JS tell me what's the point telling the user to use PHP ?
Don't you think if the user had the chance to use php he would have post this thread ?

Comment: @DrK, then read comments under the question attentively; user clearly had access to the backend since he said "i'm doing that serialize in PHP", that's why was that advice, to not use php-serialized data for the stored items; if you hit this question because you have similar problem you can create your own question

Answer (score 0):

This is not json.Some CMS like wordpress use it to store data.
you have to explode it php or split it in javascript.